# Facebook error: This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' or 'pages_read_engagement' permission

Tags: reactjs, typescript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a react application in which we use the 'react-facebook-login' npm package to make users login to Facebook. On the login call we set the scope to 'manage_pages,publish_pages' and we also tried setting it to the new manage_pages scopes according to Facebook's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/overview/permissions-features) which describes the deprecation of manage_pages permission 'pages_read_engagement,pages_manage_posts,pages_manage_metadata,pages_manage_engagement,pages_manage_ads,pages_read_user_content'.

After this login we are calling some endpoints via our backend to get long-lived access tokens and pages linked to the logged in user to be able to manage the users pages through our application.

This all works fine except when an user is trying to login multiple times in a row. If the user tries to login +- 4 times in a row we get the following error:

(#10) This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' or 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details.","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"fbtrace_id":"Ac9IFTf2PQ8E7iQzgC5B1fc"}

We have the following permissions on Facebook:

- email
- pages_manage_ads
- pages_manage_engagement
- pages_manage_metadata
- pages_manage_posts
- pages_read_engagement
- pages_read_user_content
- default

and we have the Business Asset User Profile Access feature enabled.

Can anyone tell me what we are missing or why it fails after a few logins with this message?

The endpoint giving this error is:

[https://graph.facebook.com/{pageId}?fields=access_token&access_token={accessToken}&appsecret_proof={GetAppSecretProof(accessToken)}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7BpageId%7D?fields=access_token&access_token=%7BaccessToken%7D&appsecret_proof=%7BGetAppSecretProof(accessToken)%7D)
The pageId is every accessible pageId of the user. We get these pages with the endpoint:

[https://graph.facebook.com/{userId}/accounts?access_token={accessToken}&appsecret_proof={GetAppSecretProof(accessToken)}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7BuserId%7D/accounts?access_token=%7BaccessToken%7D&appsecret_proof=%7BGetAppSecretProof(accessToken)%7D)

And last but not least we use a long lived access token for these requests which we got from the endpoint:

[https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={_configuration.ClientId}&client_secret={_configuration.ClientSecret}&fb_exchange_token={exchangeToken}](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=%7B_configuration.ClientId%7D&client_secret=%7B_configuration.ClientSecret%7D&fb_exchange_token=%7BexchangeToken%7D)
The exchangeToken is what we get from the user logging in on the frontend.

Comment: Users get asked _which_ of their pages they want to grant access to in the login dialog, I am guessing they weren’t all selected by default there, so they simply did not grant them for a couple of those pages …

Comment: I am able to reproduce the problem with all pages granting access, so unfortunately that's not the problem

Comment: What exact request causes this error message? What is the endpoint, which fields get requested, and for what specific page id(s)?